# mobilejoomla 1.2.7 not working after SEF on

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, mobilejoomla

I'm using mobilejoomla 1.2.7 to display the website in iphone browser and before SEO turned on it was working fine. But now after turning on SEF it is not even displaying home page in iphone browser. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

---

I also updated to 1.2.8 but still problem remains the same.

---

I just realized that all inside page was working properly but not just home page only.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem. In the mobilejoomla component I had set the home page forcefully, now removed the force as home page and working fine.